# How does this technology work in Tank Girl?

Tags: tank-girl

In the film [**Tank Girl**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank_Girl_(film)) (1995), the main villain Kesslee uses some technology that I find confusing. Spoilers for those who haven't seen the film:

> Halfway through the film, Kesslee has his arm severed & face mangled during a Ripper attack. The arm is replaced with a fairly standard sci-fi prosthetic, but the head is removed completely and replaced by a holographic head that (somehow) allows him to function normally.

Needless to say, this technology poses some interesting questions:

> Where is Kesslee's brain? During the final fight, he seems to think that having the holographic head means he can't be killed, which would imply that the brain is stored elsewhere. Killing him appears to actually kill him, though, which would indicate that the brain is not separate. If that's the case, was it somehow moved to his torso?

I haven't read the comic that the film is based on, but as far as I can tell this is an invention of the movie. **Has this technology been explained in any related materials or crew interviews?**

Comment: The Tank Girl graphic novelisation is no help :-(

Comment: @Richard, novelization is the wrong word when the comic came first.

Comment: @FooBar - You are mistaken. The comics came first, however there was also a [dedicated graphic novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/244124.Tank_Girl_Movie_Adaptation) **of the film**.

Comment: I'm guessing the Brain has been replaced with a tiny computer doing all the work, including making a hologram ( The tech in " Land Of The Headless" by Adam Roberts, where criminals are beheaded but not killed due to religious doctrine, reminds me of this)

Comment: Considering the mood of the movie, I'd say that his head being replaced by a hologram is supposed to be absurd.  It's part of the fun.

Comment: Pretty much the answer is no.  The comic creators never put thought into the feasibility of tech beyond does it support the aesthetic.  That lack of caring continued in the movies. Kesslee is that way because it produces an interesting visual, same with the mutant kangaroos, the brothel, canned beers post society collapse, etc.

Comment: The feel of the original comics was "*heavily influenced by punk visual art... frequently deeply disorganized, anarchic, absurdist, and psychedelic... surrealist techniques, fanzines, collage, cut-up technique, stream of consciousness, and metafiction, with very little regard or interest for conventional plot or committed narrative.*" The movie attempts (poorly) to maintain that feel while cramming it into a Hollywood scifi/action plot. This is a world where there's no water, but so much beer she uses it as ammunition. Don't expect a lot of technical accuracy. :)

Comment: @Schwern Gotta disagree about the movie makers... this film was the first I have seen (and one of the best still) to actually translate the comic *as medium* into movie form. I don't mean do a movie interpretation of the content (as, for example with MCU films), but actually bring things like the playful and conscious toying with comic frames onto the screen. I was a fan of TG before she hit the srceen, but found the movie version to be delightful (seriously: Jet Girl's see-through pants in the Cole Porter scene rocked! As did the soundtrack :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There appears to be no official explanation.

You are correct that the Kesslee's "holographic head" was invented for the 1995 film.  Unfortunately, the script does not feature any stage notes that might shed light on the technology, and there does not seem to be any official commentary on how this technology works.

That being said, Mr. Che'tsai, the individual who provided the injured Kesslee with his cybernetic enhancements, says:

> *All the king's horses*
>
> *and all the king's men*
>
> *wish they had the technology that I have.*

We can infer from this that Che'tsai has access to the some of the most advanced technology available in this fictional universe.  In keeping with this, it seems that the most likely explanations are:

- Che'tsai moved Kesslee's brain into his torso (as you suggested in your question)
- Che'tsai downloaded Kesslee's consciousness into a cybernetic implant stored somewhere in the torso (allowing him to do away with the brain completely)

The second option might better explain Kesslee's claim that he cannot be killed, as there may be backup copies of his consciousness.

Apart from this speculation, there seems to be nothing substantive that can be said.